# Orientdb, How create database in distribute mode

Tags: orientdb

I am new to orientdb. I use orientdb verson 2.1.11.

I config and deployed five nodes on the same machine in distribute mode. I use console to create a database, command is (port 2425 is the second node):

```
create database remote:192.168.12.37:2425/fuwu_test root 1234 plocal graph
```

Every node created the database "fuwu_test", but the cluster not create synchronous relationship.

I see the studio that every cluster has one cluster not five. I create one class Person, the class also not syncronized to other nodes.

Why it does't work, how to create a new datebase in running a cluster. Do I need to restart the whole nodes ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue on this in v2.1 and v2.2 releases. The workaround is creating the database before to go in cluster. Anyway it will be resolved soon, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I read http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Architecture.html ,the "Limitations".  I try the workaround.  By the way, term "cluster" confuse me, we need a placement for this word ...

Comment: I know, shame on me the day I picked that term for something other just call "collections" :-)

Comment: @Lvca: how can you "move" a created local database to the distributed network (cluster)?
I'm trying to move a db from a single server to a distributed cluster, and just importing the export to a newly created db (created through the studio) is not working out.